# Creating a Validator class for user inputs and objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net, object

So I'm just starting on a new project and am very new with this, but my basic idea is this: If I have a Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int id{ get; private set; }
    public String firstName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime age { get; private set; }
    public String LastName { get; private set; }
    public String address { get; private set; }
    public String city { get; private set; }
    public String emailAddress { get; private set; }
    
    public Customer(String firstName, String LastName, String address, String city, String emailAddress, DateTime age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
```

And want to use this validator class to check for a proper firstName

```
public class Validator
{
        public bool NameValidator(String user){
                while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || user.Length > 35)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("Name can't be empty! Input your name once more");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                }
                return true;
        }
```

What would be the best way to use the NameValidator method so that when it is true, it can create a Customer Object? Or is there a better approach?

```
Customer newCustomer = new Customer(fname);
```

Comment: I will add the functionality for the other values, but this starting point should be enough

Comment: you can write a single validator method which validates all these types as desired and return true at the end.
Else you need to create custom exceptions and throw them each time a validate fails, so the code will not be executed afterwards.
Alternatively, you can call those validate methods inside the setter methods to make sure that values are set only after validation is done.

Comment: My idea was to take user input for name, loop until is a valid name, and return, then pass that input into my customer object(validated one ofc) is it really a must to create the exceptions? Second option seems better so far

Comment: Keep names of properties consistent. Normally they start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: There two posted answers. You can pick a desired one and try. @KrauzeGodswar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least 3 options (plus mix and match):

- Validate inside constructor
- Validate in Setters
- Validate with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` ([Adding Validation to the Model (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model))

You can just:

```
public Customer(String firstName, String LastName, String address, String city, String emailAddress, DateTime age)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || firstName.Length > 35) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Bad bad name!");
        } 
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
```

Please note that if you ever deserialise the customer you need to may want to make sure that validation runs, but not necessarily at the deserialisation. You may want to run it after to provide better error handling.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

```
public class Validator
{
        public bool NameValidator(String user){
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || user.Length > 35)
                {
                      throw new Exception("user object is wrong!");
                }
                return true;
 }
```

This would break the code execution after validation fails.

**Approach 2**

Calling validations inside setter method

```
public void setName(String name){
  if(new Validator().validateName(name) == true){
   this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**Approach 3**

Ideally we should validate before calling the business logic. So you can call the validator methods as soon as you read value from the user and prompt to enter again.
What I would do is first read value, then validate values seperately and get the inserted again if wrong and finally process values.